# Javascript: set width and height for the image

Tags: javascript

can someone help me to set width and height for the image in the code below? Unfortunately, I have zero knowledge of javascript and tips from the google didn't work. I need to set the these values for my image: width: 150px, height: 60px.
Thank you.

```
<script>
PayPal.Donation.Button({
env:'production',
hosted_button_id:'XXXXXXXX',
image: {
src:'assets/img/donate-main.png',
alt:'Donate with PayPal button',
title:'PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!',
}
}).render('#donate-button');
```

Comment: You don't set it with JS. Style your #donate-button with CSS. (And/or style the container of this item)

Comment: You're using PayPal integration. Which of their APIs are you using exactly?

Comment: @Wimanicesir, thank you. I have styled it with CSS, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this after the button is rendered, after that piece of code?

```
document.getElementById("donate-button").width = "300";
document.getElementById("donate-button").height = "300";
```

WHat are you using to render the button?

Comment: Though this answer OP's question. Is this really the best approach? I would advise to use CSS instead :)